# Why isn't this ttk.Separator not expanding properly?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

For some reason, the vertical separator is not expanding. This is what I did:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import Separator

root = Tk()

Label(root, text='Apples').grid(column=0, row=0)
Label(root, text='Oranges').grid(column=2, row=0)
Label(root, text='Pears').grid(column=4, row=0)
Label(root, text='Cherries').grid(column=0, row=2)
Label(root, text='Avocados').grid(column=2, row=2)
Label(root, text='Bananas').grid(column=4, row=2)
Separator(root, orient=HORIZONTAL).grid(row=1, columnspan=10, sticky=(W,E))
Separator(root, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=1, rowspan=3, sticky=(S,N))

mainloop()
```

This is the result:

[image: Separator]

As you can see in the bottom-left side of the window, the vertical separator appears like a small line. How do I expand it using the the `.grid()` method?

Bonus question: What would be the correct way to add a second vertical separator on the 3rd column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify `rowspan`, it means that the widget will span its row and any rows *below* it. Because you didn't specify a row, the separator was in row 3.

To fix this, specify row 0:

```
Separator(root, orient=VERTICAL).grid(row = 0, column=1, rowspan=3, sticky=(S,N))
```

As for the bonus question, you add another separator the way you did the first.

```
Separator(root, orient=VERTICAL).grid(row = 0, column=3, rowspan=3, sticky=(S,N))
```